# Flutter: Offstage with Navigator inside not getting focus

Tags: dart, flutter, navigator

In my App I have a bottom bar that is always visible. I found in [this site](http://bizz84.github.io/2018/07/07/Multiple-Navigators-BottomNavigationBar.html) that a good way to keep tabs in memory while also having multiple navigators is by using Offscreen. However, when I put a Navigator inside Offscreen none of its contents can receive focus. I made a very simple example that reproduces what I'm saying:

```
void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Offstage(
              offstage:false,
              child: Navigator(
                onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
                  return MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return Center(child: TextField());
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),

            Offstage(
              offstage:true,
              child: Navigator(
                onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
                  return MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return Center(child: TextField());
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you click on the TextField, it will not receive focus, so the user cannot type anything.

Is there any way to direct focus to the active (visible) offscreen ?
Any other suggestion for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is a current issue in Github. To solve it you need to put a FocusScope widget on top of each Navigator.

This comment in the GH thread has an example:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17098#issuecomment-414610135